# How to remote events in .NET Remoting?

Tags: c#, .net, events, .net-remoting

I have a class for remoting which contains events. But when I am trying to set handler for those events on the client side I receive exception. My code looks like:

```
    //In common library
    class RemoteClass : MarshalByRefObject
    {
    public event EventHandler SomeEvent = null;

    public void SomeMethod () {}
    }

    //On client-side
    RemoteClass r = (RemoteClass) RemotingServer.Connect (typeof(RemoteClass), "myURL");

    r.SomeMethod (); //Everything is OK here.

    r.SomeEvent += delegate (object o, EventArgs e) { }; //Exception:Type
```

`System.DelegateSerializationHolder` and the types derived from it (such as `System.DelegateSerializationHolder`) are not permitted to be deserialized at this security level.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: well, what is the security level? either change that, or... don't use remoting.

Comment: I didn't understand anything form your comment :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://web.archive.org/web/20141009214120/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/61w7kz4b(v=vs.80).aspx

> In the .NET Framework, the default security level for distributed communication (remoting) is low. This affects passing the user-defined object type to remote methods. You might need to adjust the default security level to full in some cases to allow serialization of objects.

If you're in ASP.Net, here's how to set the security (trust) level:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648344.aspx

Comment: The first link is dead now?

Comment: @StayOnTarget yeah, that happens sometimes. I updated it with an archive.org link. Looks like it's not getting the style sheet, but the content is at least readable. I think it more or less just says what I copy-pasted into the answer anyhow though.